# How to wait for a response after a certain command?

Tags: java, android

Here is a line of code that I have:

```
public class ReminderHandler()  {
  if (edittext.containsReminderWords()){
  test.setText("Do you want me to remind you to " + sharedPref.getString(toremember, toremember) + "?");
    }
}
```

I want the program to wait for either a yes or a no answer from the edittext after this specific line of command.

I have no idea how though.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you consider alertdialog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to know more about android Dialogs

Answer (score 1):

JOptionPane has plenty of options for you to use.

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to do something?")
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) for the documentation

Answer (score 0):

you would do this with an event:

- a button near the text input that say something like "do it"/"save"/"done", etc.
- an event, like focus changed, touch up,etc. see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html